# spring security intercept-url access

Tags: spring-security

in our app, we have the following:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER,ROLE_CUST_ADMIN" />
```

but, in our app, we can create custom roles too, and, when a user of a custom role, for ex, `ROLE_LIMITED_USER` tries login, the access is denied.

how can I secure the app without listing the roles ? or how can I make it accept a pattern `ROLE_*` ?

I tried the following :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```

but, this is causing the session time out and user is required to login. Before the change, the user login was remembered.

Appreciate any solution
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple things:

1. The roles that you are requiring to access functionality in your app should not change - think of them more as "permissions" instead of "roles". (The Spring Security default here may be a misnomer.) Then you can map sets of permissions to roles (via your own code), allowing custom roles to be created as a different bag of permissions, but the actual permissions that you are coding/checking against are static - they don't change. When a user is authenticated, the set of `GrantedAuthority`s you populate in the `UserDetails` should be a merged collection of **permissions** based on the user's assigned **roles**.
2. That said, I think you can still do what you want without changing the security model by using [Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access). Assuming you're using the security namespace (i.e. `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"`), then you need to set `use-expressions="true"` on the `<http>` element and change your `access` attribute values to SpEL expressions, such as:

   ```
   <http use-expressions="true">
       <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER','ROLE_CUST_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/other1/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/other2/**" access="authentication.authorities.?[authority.startsWith('ROLE_')].size() != 0" />
   </http>
   ```

Note that this code snippet has not been tested, and I'm pretty sure the 3rd `intercept-url` example won't work as is but should be pretty close. (It's attempting to filter the `Collection<GrantedAuthority>` to authorities that start with `ROLE_` and make sure the filtered list isn't empty.)

My guess is that it will be easier to use the 2nd `intercept-url` and do any further custom checking in code, where you can get access to the current `SecurityContext` / `Authentication` / principal via:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

Hope this helps.

Note similar question here as well:
[Spring Security Authorize Access Role with a Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337039/spring-security-authorize-access-role-with-a-wildcard)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried the following methods, but, in all cases, my app is failing in other areas. It turned out that removing that intercept-url check is causing some other side effects. I thought, I was only removing an access check , but, something else is broken .. 1) I tried SpEl with custom method . the method got called , but my app is failing in other pages .. So, your suggestion/solution worked , but, there are other issues I need to take care in the app.  Thank you for the answer. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring's `@PreAuthorize` annotations in your classes, and reference a custom permission evaluator via [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html). Don't worry about building an expression parser, as you can simply reference a boolean method from within the annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("@myCustomClass.booleanMethod(param1, param2, #passedParam) and isAuthenticated()")
myMethod(passedParam) {
    //do something
}
```

Then, in the custom class, define the boolean method, and it can handle your roles (permissions) however you like -- including accessing a database to discover your newly added roles.

You won't be able to add new roles to the XML configuration on the fly, so if your question pertains to new role creation (which seems to be the case), you'll need something like the above to make it happen. Using SpEL and a custom boolean method gives you access to a potentially limitless set of restrictions and requirements you can add to your application.

Comment: We already have service layer security with the help of the annotations and evaluator as you explained. For my intercept-url problem, I thought just removing that check will solve my issue, as we do the authentication checks in the app anyways .. But, when I removed that intercept-url check, the app is failing in other areas. I am wondering there are side affects to this check that kept the app in shape .. do not know what.

Comment: Strange. My app doesn't use `<intercept-url/>` at all; I removed them in favor of controller-level security via my custom permission evaluator. I wish I could help more. Good luck!